# How to restore previous session in Firefox 36.0.4

Tags: firefox

I use a bat file to open FireFox.  In the bat file, I will copy the sessionstore.js to my own directory as backup.  Then, when FF crash, I can copy  the backup file to replace the sessionstore.js

Also, sometimes I will open 2 FF windows (one with 100 tabs and one with 2 tabs).  When I close the 100-tab window first and then the 2-tab window, FF will re-open the 2-tab in next run.  Then, I have to copy the backup file to replace the sessionstore.js.  Using this method, I will get back the 100-tab window.

I use this method for many years and everything work fine.

Today, due to careless, I re-do the 100-tab-2-tab scenario.

However, today with FireFox 36.0.4, this method does not work. I have tried 3 times to copy back the sessionstore.js.  However, it always open the 2-tab window.

Now, even with the 100-tab sessionstore.js file, I cannot tell FireFox 36.0.4 to use it.  It seems to me that FireFox 36.0.4 uses a new method for session handling.  There are new directories named 'sessions' and 'sessionstore-backups' in C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXX.default

Could any FireFox expert helps on this situation ?

Many thanks.